# CollapsingToolbarLayout title disappears after switching Activity

Tags: android

I have a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in a `fragment` with a `layout` and `Toobar` inside it like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="@color/color_red_800"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    <include layout="@layout/header_profile_1" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:title="Toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_custom_profile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/color_transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

And I set the title of the `Toolbar` using this code on the Java

```
collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Profile");
collapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleColor(Color.alpha(0));
collapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Now it works fine but when I switch to another `Activity` while the `Toolbar` is in collapsed condition, the title disappears. This doesn't happen if the Toolbar is in expanded condition.

Answer (score 0):

try this code. and i hope it will help you

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/list_item"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/forty_dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <include layout="@layout/header_profile_1" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
```

and set the title by using below code

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
mToolbar.setTitle("");
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply unfortunately it doesnt work.